# Why does the range of this integral work out this way?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, integration, dirac-delta-distributions

I have a bit of trouble in finding the same limits for the integral in Eq. (17.111) from Peskin & Schroeder. We have something like
$$ \int_0^1 dx' \int_0^1 dz f(x',z) \delta(x-zx').$$
Posing $y=zx'$, I find
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 dz \int_0^1 \frac{dy}{z} f\biggl(\frac{y}{z},z\biggr) \delta(x-y)
&= \int_0^1 \frac{dz}{z} 1_{[0,z]}f\biggl(\frac{x}{z},z\biggr)\\
&= \int_0^z \frac{dz}{z} f\biggl(\frac{x}{z},z\biggr).
\end{align}$$
Instead, P&S find
$$ \int_x^1 \frac{dz}{z} f\biggl(\frac{x}{z},z\biggr).$$
I must have overlooked some property of the Delta distribution. Can someone point out my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

P&S's equation implicitly assumes that $0\leq x\leq 1$:
$$\begin{align}\int_{[0,1]} \!dz &\int_{[0,1]} \!dx'  ~f(x',z)~ \delta(x-zx')\cr
~=~&\int_{[0,1]} \!dz\int_{\mathbb{R}} \!dx'  ~1_{[0,1]}(x')~f(x',z)~ \frac{1}{|z|}\delta(\frac{x}{z}-x')\cr~=~&\int_{[0,1]} \!\frac{dz}{|z|}   1_{[0,1]}(\frac{x}{z})~f(\frac{x}{z},z)\cr~=~&\int_{[0,1]} \!\frac{dz}{|z|}   1_{[0,1]}(x)~\theta(z\!-\!x)~f(\frac{x}{z},z)\cr~=~&1_{[0,1]}(x)\int_{[x,1]} \!\frac{dz}{z}~f(\frac{x}{z},z).\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

The scaling property of the Dirac delta is 
$$\delta(\alpha x) = {1\over|\alpha|} \delta(x). $$ 
So you get
$$ 
\int_0^1 dx' \int_0^1 dz f(x',z) \delta(x-zx') =  \int_0^1 dz \int_0^z \frac{dy}{z} f({y\over z},z) \delta(x-y)
$$
meaning that when you apply the delta function you have $x\leq z$